# sequence of set, strict investment

Tags: probability-theory

\begin{align*}
X^+=\limsup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X_n &= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\bigcup_{j=n}^{\infty} X_j\right)\\\
X^-=\liminf_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X_n &= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\bigcap_{j=n}^{\infty} X_j\right).
\end{align*} I am trying to show that exist sequence of events $[X_i]^{\infty}_{i=1}$ for whiсh $X^-\subset X^+$ (strict investment)
I think the expample is when we take $X_i$ as $X_i=A$ when $i$ is even and $X_i=B$ when $i$ is odd. But i cant show it strictly.

Comment: To be clear, do you want $X^-\subsetneq X^+$?

Comment: @MPW, I know that this is true for any sequence of sets. But i want to costract the exatly example when exist the $A\in X^+$, but $A\notin X^-$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think your alternating example will work as long as $A\neq B$, since in that case I think
$$\limsup_n X_n = A\cup B$$
and
$$\liminf_n X_n = A\cap B$$

and, since these are distinct if $A\neq B$, then $A\cap B\subsetneq A\cup B$.

Comment: Yes, i am trying to proof stricly that $X^+=A\cup B$ and $X^-=A\cap B$

Comment: Isn't this clear in your case? Surely these follow immediately from the facts that $\bigcup_{j\geq n}X_j$ is either $A\cup B\cup A\cup B\cup \cdots = A\cup B$ or  $B\cup A\cup B\cup A\cup \cdots = A\cup B$, and $\bigcap_{j\geq n}X_j$ is either $A\cap B\cap A\cap B\cap \cdots = A\cap B$ or $B\cap A\cap B\cap A\cap \cdots = A\cap B$ right?

Comment: yes, it is obviously

Comment: So what is left to show? Are you having trouble showing that $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ are not equal if $A$ and $B$ are not equal?

Comment: i am just afraid oversimplified explanation ;)